# Inconsistent behavior from compactenum from paralist package

Tags: paralist

I've set up a macro that I call `compactEnumAlphi` using the `compactenum` environment that's in the `paralist.sty` package.     I want it to generate lists that look like:

```
a) first
b) second
```

etc.    But the macro performs differently depending on whether it's embedded in an `itemize` environment or an `enumerate` environment.   As the example below will illustrate, it works as intended in the latter case but not in the former.   Inside the `itemize` environment, an additional `)` is added, producing

```
 a)) first
 b)) second
```

Could anybody advise please?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{paralist}
\newenvironment{compactEnumAlphi}{
    \parskip=0pt
    \parindent=0pt
    \begin{compactenum}[$\quad$a) ]
    \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
    }
    {\end{compactenum} 
     {\parskip=12 pt plus 0 pt minus 0 pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Hullo world
    \begin{compactEnumAlphi}
        \item two Hullo worlds
    \end{compactEnumAlphi}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Hullo world
    \begin{compactEnumAlphi}
        \item two Hullo worlds
    \end{compactEnumAlphi}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you redefine \theenumi in your environment?

Comment: `\newenvironment{compactEnumAlphi}{\begin{compactenum}[\quad a) ]}{\end{compactenum}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi})}` has no effect in the first case, because the `compactenum` environment is a second level enumeration; in the second case it does, but `paralist` features do a redefinition of the labeling mechanism, and your redefition confuses the compiler.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{paralist}

\newenvironment{compactEnumAlphi}
  {\begin{compactenum}[\quad a) ]}
  {\end{compactenum}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Hullo world
    \begin{compactEnumAlphi}
        \item two Hullo worlds
    \end{compactEnumAlphi}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Hullo world
    \begin{compactEnumAlphi}
        \item two Hullo worlds
    \end{compactEnumAlphi}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Note that resetting `\parindent` has essentially no effect; your code

```
{\end{compactenum} 
  {\parskip=12 pt plus 0 pt minus 0 pt}}
```

does nothing at all after `\end{compactenum}`: setting a parameter in a group is a complicated way to do nothing.

If you have set `\parskip` at the outer level (which is something I never recommend, you can reset it in the `compactEnumAlphi` environment. Such a resetting will be undone as soon as the environment ends.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{paralist}

\newenvironment{compactEnumAlphi}
  {%\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.1pt}% uncomment if you need it
   \begin{compactenum}[\quad a) ]}
  {\end{compactenum}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Hullo world
    \begin{compactEnumAlphi}
        \item two Hullo worlds
    \end{compactEnumAlphi}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Hullo world
    \begin{compactEnumAlphi}
        \item two Hullo worlds
    \end{compactEnumAlphi}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you have nested `enumerate`s the first level takes `enumi`, and the second level uses `enumii` (which is unmodified by your definition).  In the second example, you are at the first level of enumeration, thus the counter used is `enumi`.  The optional parameter of the `compactenum` environment, gives the instruction to print a space (`\quad`) then take the current value of the enumeration at the current level in alphabetic form (`a`) and then print a parenthesis.  In the first case the value of the current enumeration is given by the counter `enumii` and `\theenumii` just prints the value of the counter;  in the second example the counter used is `enumi` and the modified `\theenumi` prints the value of the counter plus a parenthesis.